# Visualize .net core code coverage directly in Azure Pipelines

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a .net core project with pipeline (YAML, multi-stage) pipeline set up in Azure DevOps. We have a bunch of unit tests that we execute at pipeline run time - everything is fine.

However - we would like to dig more deeper into our code coverage. So we have configured our task like this

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run UnitTests
  enabled: true
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/PM.UnitTests.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'
```

The result is this

[image]

We can now see this in pipeline results:

[image]

This .coverage file can be downloaded and analyzed in e.g. Visual Studio.

However - we would really like to be able to see the results directly in Azure Pipelines. We have a Typescript project where we do this. The result is this:
[image]

Sadly, it is not at all apparent to me how to apply this to a .net core project.

**Q1: Is it possible to have the same experience for .net core projects ... and how?**

Additionally - we would like to be able to apply filtering on which parts of the code is used to calculate the code coverage percentage.

**Q2: Is it correctly understood that this is done using a *.runsettings* file?**

Thank you :-)

/Jesper

For reference, this is my complete YAML pipeline in my test .net core solution. The solution is super simple - a .net core class library and a .net core test class library

[image]

```
pool:
  vmImage: vs2017-win2016

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'd12c137f-dac4-4ea7-bc39-59bd2b784537'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run UnitTests
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/Test.Coverage/Test.Coverage.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" '
- script: 'dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool  '
  displayName: 'Install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool'
- script: 'reportgenerator -reports:$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(build.sourcesdirectory) -reporttypes:"Cobertura"'
  displayName: 'Executes reportgenerator'
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage from $(build.sourcesdirectory)/Cobertura.xml'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/Cobertura.xml'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the  [dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool/)  package to generate the HTML Code Coverage Report.

Here is an example:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '$(Parameters.TestProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" '

- script: 'dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool  '
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- script: 'reportgenerator -reports:$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(build.sourcesdirectory) -reporttypes:"Cobertura"'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage from $(build.sourcesdirectory)/Cobertura.xml'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/Cobertura.xml'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you so much! I had a bit of an issue getting the data collector to work right, but this question on SO helped me to figure out to add a reference to the coverlet collector on nuget https://stackoverflow.com/a/58885761/670816

Comment: It worked for me, however instead of pushing the report to the Code Coverage tab, it was published as a artifact in azure devops, do you know what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a tool that can generate a report based on the coverage information. You're looking for a [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator).

> ReportGenerator converts coverage reports generated by coverlet, OpenCover, dotCover, Visual Studio, NCover, Cobertura, JaCoCo, Clover, gcov or lcov into human readable reports in various formats.

There are quite a few examples out there working with the [dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool) for .NET Core projects.

You might find this [Learn -> Usage page](https://danielpalme.github.io/ReportGenerator/usage.html) helpful.

[Coverlet](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet) might also be an interesting addition to your toolbelt.